# Get current time in PHP like 12:33:00

Tags: php, time

I am trying to get current time in PHP so that I can store this in the Database.

When I do

```
$currentTime = time();
```

or

```
$currentTime = time('hh:ii:ss');
```

I get a result which is like

> 1428492931

but I want the time to be the correct format such as

> 12:33:00

Comment: And the problem/question is ?

Comment: read the manual first http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is date not time function

```
date('h:i:s');
```

`time` — Return current Unix timestamp

Description

> int time ( void ) Returns the current time measured in the number of
>   seconds since the Unix Epoch (January 1 1970 00:00:00 GMT).